# how to Read a folder on local machine and load them in a silverlight control?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am implementing a silverlight application in that I need to read a folder which has images in it. That folder is in my local machine. I want to access that folder to my silverlight code behind.After that i want to load all those images into Listbox control( or any other control to display images one by one. ) to display them one by one. Here I have next and previous buttons to move images.

Answer (score 1):

You can access local files in [Silverlight 4](http://devmeat.com/show/5912490) if running as a trusted application, but not in [Silverlight 3](http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/08/17/Reading-Local-Files-in-Silverlight.aspx) without user interaction.

Note also "[you can access only files in user folders, specifically the MyDocuments, MyMusic, MyPictures, and MyVideos folders.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) "

Answer (score 0):

Nope you can't do this, you would need SL4 OOB with Elevated Trust to be able to this.